# Disable "Git for Windows 32-bit" process when using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: git, visual-studio

whenever I work with Visual Studio 2017, I notice that the "Git for Windows (32 bit)" appears in the task manager process bar.

I'm not working with Git, is it possible to configure VS so that it doesn't create this process? It's quite memory-greedy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was [reported before](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24816/gitexe-is-still-being-opened-even-if-git-source-co.html), although with a procedure supposed to cancel that process:

> If I understand, you are "connected" with a TFS / VSTS Team Project (in Team Explorer) with Git repositories. You switch the `Current Source Control Plug-in` (in `Tools > Options > Source Control > Plug-in Selector`) to `None`, but it does not stick.
>   **This is currently expected behavior - if you are connected to a TFS / VSTS Git Team Project, then the client integration cannot be "permanently" disabled**.
>   You can switch it off, but many actions will re-enable it.
>   You can disable both the TFS / VSTS integration and the local Git integration, or have them both enabled.
>
> If you want to turn off the Git integration, you can
>
> - 1st disconnect from your current project (`"Team" menu -> "Disconnect from Team Foundation Server"`),
> - and then you should be able to remove this project from your list of connections.
>
> After this, you should be able to turn off your Source Control Plugin (set it to none), and the Git integration should not come back on.